# Strange notice in apache error log

Tags: log-files, apache-2.4

Today I found a strange notice in apache error.logs. The log tells me the following:

```
[Mon Mar 24 06:26:34.872366 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 32214] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Mar 24 06:26:34.872417 2014] [core:notice] [pid 32214] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

What I find strange about it is that I was not touching apache during that time. When I checked info from the `last` command I have not found anyone connecting to the machine anywhere close to this time.

I also was not able to find any `404` requests during this time in access log.

So my question is, what could have caused these logs (as I understood apache restarted itself) and is it normal.

**Sorry for not including this**. I am on ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-58-virtual x86_64), which is actually Amazon AWS.

**Update about cron**: `/etc/cron.d` has only two files:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  510 Feb 13 16:06 php5
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  102 Apr  2  2012 .placeholder
```

`.placeholder` is empty (only one line of comments is inside)
`php5` has this inside

```
# /etc/cron.d/php5: crontab fragment for php5
#  This purges session files older than X, where X is defined in seconds
#  as the largest value of session.gc_maxlifetime from all your php.ini
#  files, or 24 minutes if not defined.  See /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime

# Look for and purge old sessions every 30 minutes
09,39 *     * * *     root   [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -x /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean /var/lib/php5 $(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime)
```

**Update on logrotate**
Yes approximately during this time `access.log.1` and `error.log.1` were created

```
Mar 23 06:51 access.log.1
Mar 24 06:26 error.log.1
```

Comment: Which OS/Distro and what time was it ? Did it happen just once or many times ?

Comment: Do you have a cron job that hits /usr/bin/apache2?

Comment: @Iain OS added. This happened just once. But the system is only started 2 weeks ago.

Comment: @Ahrotahntee I have not configured any cron jobs. Can you please tell how can I check if there is something?

Comment: @SalvadorDali You can see if the package came with any by looking in /etc/cron.d/ - look for Apache.

Comment: @Ahrotahntee thank you. I added information about cron.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you're not giving away the time (which might aid in tying this down) I'm going to point my finger at [logrotate](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) carrying out it's weekly rotation of the apache logs.

Logrotate is called by the /etc/crontab line that runs cron.daily (at 06:25 on my system) and the rules for apache2 can be found in /etc/logrotate.d/apache2.

Comment: thanks, I updated information about time (sorry I thought it is not important) and logrotate.

Comment: Looks like we have a smokimg gun.

Comment: @lain can you please clarify what do you mean?

Comment: @SalvadorDali: It looks like I'm right - logrotate is likely the cause of the message.